# Elastic Query to have recently added items by each client

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write an elastic query and am new to writing queries in elastic search.

I need to write a query that gets the recently added 20 items with a maximum of 2-3 items from a particular category. If there were few categories, then I need to display items from available categories

I tried to write an aggregation query like below

```
GET elastic-table/_search 
{
  "size": 20,
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "catalog"        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By running this query, I am able to aggregate all the distinct catalog keywords in an elastic table,  but I need to fetch the recently added items under each catalog keyword. Can anyone help with this?

```
Already tried Queries:

Query 1:

GET elastic-table/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "createddate": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I am able to sort by created date, but not by distinct categories

Query 2: 

GET elastic-table/_search 
{
  "size": 20,
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "catalog"        
      }
    }
  }
}

I am able to get distinct categories but not recently added items in them

Query 3:

GET elastic-table/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "createddate": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
      "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "catalog"        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to get data sorted by date but data is not having distinct categories

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

There is a slight possibility that theres a limitation of 10 results per query if I recall correctly. But the link above is pretty much the same problem you are asking

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "GroupByType": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "catalog"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "Group": {
                    "top_hits":{
                        "size":20, #Will return at most 20 records
                        "_source": {
                                "include": [(include any parameters you want returned here)]
                        },
                        "sort":[{ #will sort by lowest value first
                            "created date": {
                            "order": "asc"
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```